# querySelectorAll faster for animations than getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript, performance

Assuming we wanted to animate 100 div elements and we select all of those and store them in a `nodeList` using `querySelectorAll` and `getElementsByClassName`. It is known that the preparation is much faster with the latter than with the first since the first needs all the dom data from the start. However, `querySelectorAll` is static, so I wonder how much faster it is when using it to manipulate dom data via, lets say `requestanimationframe`.

Any ideas?

Comment: See jsperf's getElementsByClassName[0] VS querySelector - https://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-queryselectorall/196

Comment: Are you creating/removing matching divs all the time?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no, just moving them and changing css.

Comment: @OriDrori ya I know that site. Tested it there. Its slower when creating the list but that is obvious why.

Comment: But if your not adding/removing elements the selection process won't effect the animation.

Comment: @OriDrori whew good to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not adding and removing matching divs (including changing classes on existing divs so they join or leave the list), it doesn't really matter; grab the list **once**, and then do the animation from that list.

If you're adding/removing matching divs, use `getElementsByClassName`, since (again) you can grab the list **once** and then work from that list (which is continually updated by the browser). (If you need to support IE8, this is not an option; IE8 has `querySelectorAll`, but not `getElementsByClassName`. But IE8 is obsolete, so...)

Comment: Oh ok, so the update doesnt refer to changes in attributes , css etc

Comment: @Asperger: No, you'd have to change the class such that an element joined or left the list for it to matter.

Comment: Oh, I see. Ok, so I was worrying for nothing.

Comment: You know whats so weird though. Now I swapped everything to querySelectorAll and animation seems smoother. So weird, or maybe its because I restarted my laptop xD

Answer (score 2):

However you select those nodes doesn't matter because in the animation function you should only be using the stored references to those nodes.

Comment: Indeed but when I change values the live node list changes as well. Its kind of like an infinite loop or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "change values"? Do you alter the amount of nodes to be animated?

Comment: No, I just alter some inline styles

Comment: Then the list of nodes to be animated does not change at all, so you don't have to (and you shouldn't) reselect those nodes.